# inbuilt algorithm for max or min of an array

Tags: stl, max, min

I am trying to find out the inbuilt mechanism of how does the max or min function work in c++ in STL for finding the maximum or minimum element in an array of elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In STL, it's `min_element` and `max_element` respectively, and it accepts `Iterator` as the parameter type rather than the collection itself. It is not called `min` and `max` in order to prevent name collision with the CRT `min` and `max` functions/macros.

It is well-documented here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/min_element/

Note that `Iterator` is a stand-in for a variety of types, including raw pointers.

Example:

```
int myints[] = {3,7,2,5,6,4,9};
std::cout << "The smallest element is " << *std::min_element( myints, myints+7 ) << '\n';
```

Comment: Actually, it's not called `min` or `max` because the STL already has functions called `min` and `max`, and they take the minimum/maximum of two values. If you called `min(iterator, iterator)`, it would attempt to find the lesser of the two iterators.  As @Dai said, for a sequence, use `min_element` or `max_element`, which return you an iterator to the element that you want (hence the `*` in his code)